# State-transition matrix

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, linear-systems

I am studying the observability properties of a dynamical system and I get to the next equations:
$$x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$$
$$A(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$
$$\Phi(t,t_{0}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$
$$$$

$$\dot{x}(t) = A(t)x(t) \hspace{1cm} x(t=0) = x_{0}$$
$$\frac{d\Phi(t,t_{0})}{dt} = A(t)\Phi(t,t_{0}) \hspace{1cm} \Phi(t=0) = I$$

What are the mathematical derivation to get to the point:
$$x(t) = \Phi(t,t_{0}) x_{0}$$
being $\Phi(t,\tau)$ the Peano–Baker series:
$$\mathbf{\Phi}(t,\tau) = \mathbf{I} + \int_\tau^t\mathbf{A}(\sigma_1)\,d\sigma_1 + \int_\tau^t\mathbf{A}(\sigma_1)\int_\tau^{\sigma_1}\mathbf{A}(\sigma_2)\,d\sigma_2\,d\sigma_1 + \int_\tau^t\mathbf{A}(\sigma_1)\int_\tau^{\sigma_1}\mathbf{A}(\sigma_2)\int_\tau^{\sigma_2}\mathbf{A}(\sigma_3)\,d\sigma_3\,d\sigma_2\,d\sigma_1 + ...$$

Here it is the proof that this solution is correct.
If we derive the equation proposed as the solution we get:
$$\dot{x}(t) = \frac{d\Phi(t,t_{0})}{dt} x_{0} = A(t)\Phi(t,t_{0}) x_{0} = A(t)x(t)$$
so the solution proposed $x$ is correct.

But my initial doubt still remains open. How can I mathematically get to the solution from the 2 equations?
The solution can be found in Linear System Theory, Wilson J. Rugh (Second Edition 1996) in Chapter 3.

Comment: At the first glance the question does not contain enough information to give an answer. It is not clear at all what $y(t)$ is doing here.

Comment: Edited to be clearer.

Comment: I am still not sure what $A(t)$ means. Perhaps you could give more context for the problem? What is $x(t)$? What is $\Phi$?

Comment: The thing is that theoretically using the first 2 equations should be enough to get to the last equation. Basically $$x$$ is the state vector in an LTI system and $$\Phi$$ is defined as the state-transition matrix.

Comment: The straightforward approach is to integrate both equations, assuming that $A(t)$ is a known function. They are both linear odes of the first order.

Comment: Could you also check the equation for $\Phi(t,t_0)$ - shouldn't it have $A(t)$ instead of $x(t)$?

Comment: You are right, I am sorry for the typo. 
My initial idea was to find a way to get to the last equation through matrix operations, I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: You can solve matrix equations of this time just like the first order ODEs, using matrix exponents, and keeping the track of the ordering of matrices. If you solve the equation for $x(t)$ you can read out from it readily function $\Phi(t,t_0)$ and then simply show that it satisfies the required equation. Btw, I suppose that $\Phi(t_0,t_0)=1$.

Comment: Nop, $$\Phi(t=0)$$ is a matrix, the Identity matrix. I can not use matrix exponents because the coefficients of the matrix are not constant.

Comment: Have you ever derived an evolution operator in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Nop, I have not studied quantom mechanics.

Comment: Then I suppose that you need to look up the solution in the textbook for your course - because the derivation is straightforward but lengthy.

Comment: This is not a problem in quantum mechanics but dynamical systems. If you could tell me any book in which this derivation is presented I would be very grateful.

Comment: The derivation is the same, but I am not very familiar with the literature on dynamical systems. Sorry, I can't help here.

Comment: I finally found it. The mathematical proof can be found in Linear System Theory, Wilson J. Rugh (Second Edition 1996).

Answer (score 1):

$\Phi(t, t_0)$ is the matrix made by assembling columns out of the $x(t)$  with initial conditions at $t_0$. The first column has initial data
$x(t_0)=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)^T$; the second column is $x(t)$ with initial data $x(t_0)=(0,1,0,\ldots 0)^T$; and so on. Then, by the linearity of the equations of motion
$$
x(t)= \Phi(t, t_0) x(t_0)
$$
is the solution for general initial data.

Comment: So, another equation is needed in order to get to the last equation right?

Comment: No. It's all there in what I said.  $\Phi$ is a matrix whose columns are the evolution a basis  set of initial conditions. No other information needed. It's a linear system of equations after all...

Comment: "Φ(t,t0)  is the matrix made by assembling columns out of the x(t) with initial conditions at t0. The first column has initial data x(t0)=(1,0,0,…,0)T; the second column is x(t) with initial data x(t0)=(0,1,0,…0)T; and so on."

This logic is not in the equations I wrote or am I missing something?

Comment: You seem to be  missing the   linearity: If $x(t_0) = \lambda x_1(t_0)+\mu x_2(t_0)$ then $x(t) =\lambda x_1(t)+\mu x_2(t)$ so there is a basis set of solutions, just like any linear ODE.

Comment: Ok, so another equation was needed. Thank-you.

Comment: No. The linearity is already explicit in your equation $\dot x(t)= A(t)x(t)$. From it you immediatly deduce that  $d(\lambda x_1+\mu x_2)/dt =A(\lambda x_1+\mu x_2)$.

Comment: Ok, I don't think that is correct. You are doing an assumption on linearity that I am not doing. Anyway, thank-you for your time.

Comment: How is it not correct?  There is no way for the equation $\dot x =Ax$ not to be linear unless $A$ depends on $x$ in addition to $t$. Of course in that case all bets are off, and $\Phi$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, that is true for any linear differential equation system. Now, what does that have to do with the logic you proposed to generate the matrix $\Phi$?